# How to query google maps from React Native iOS linking

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native

I have an app with google maps link like this

```
const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${label}`,
      android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});
Linking.canOpenURL(url)
```

What I want to do is to query google maps using query=${lat},${lon} and using the name described as label above, because when I do the query, google maps open at the location but the pin displays the lat and long, and I want to display the label string

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. If you have google maps installed it will open the app with the desired location and pin correctly. If you don't have google maps installed it will open the browser with google maps and location! :)

```
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
    const latLng = `${your Lat},${your Long}`;
    const label = this.state.clinic.name;
    const url = Platform.select({
      ios: `https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${label}&center=${lat},${long}`,
      android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
    });
    Linking.canOpenURL(url)
    .then((supported) => {
        if (!supported) {
            browser_url =
            "https://www.google.de/maps/@" +
            latitude +
            "," +
            longitude +
            "?q=" +
            label;
            return Linking.openURL(browser_url);
        } else {
            return Linking.openURL(url);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('error', err));
```